# How to solve "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or corrupted"?

Tags: android

I needed to free up some disk space so I deleted my `C:\ADT` folder because I assumed it was from my old android eclipse days.  Now when I open android studio it says "please provide the path to the android sdk" with a link that takes me to the android studio dowload page.  The only down load items I see there are android studio and sdk tools.  I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling android studio, but the problem still persisted.  I've also tried downloading `sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip` from that the android studio download site but android studio didn't recognize the sdk when I pointed it to the extracted contents with "The selected directory is not a valid home for Android SDK"

When I click on "SDK Manager" icon in android studio, It opens, but when I check anything to download, it says "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted.  Clicking "Open SDK Manager" opens literally the same window again.

[image]

Also possibly relevant:  I have to install Android Studio as a different user (with admin rights) than the user that I use to run Android studio.

Comment: If you have not removed from Recycle than it will recovered from that..

Comment: @UpendraShah I was using shift+delete, since my goal was to free up space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was related to the fact that I had to install Android Studio as a different user (with admin rights) than my normal windows account.

After trying all the steps outlined in my question, I tried running android studio as my special admin rights user account, and it provided a special start up screen that prompted me to download the android sdk for the first time.  I didn't get that startup screen when running as my normal windows user, just got the errors as indicated in the question.

Note that when I was prompted to install the sdk, I selected "custom" install so that my android sdk would be installed into a common area and not in the private app data area for my admin user account.  Then when I ran as my normal user, I was able to select that same location for the android SDK.

Comment: Hey, just used this advice again.  Thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. When Android Studio started it loaded an old project I had been working on a long time ago. I closed that project, and then Android Studio realized that the SDK wasn't installed and went ahead installing it. So a fix could be to try to close any open solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only android sdk tools and don't want to download android studio all over again then go to this link, https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

scroll down to command line tools and download the sdk. It's a 132 mb file.

[image]

Comment: See my updated question, I had tried downloading that but android studio wouldn't recognize the sdk there when i tried to set the sdk path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the fix was simple. THe install directory where the SDK should go didn't exist. I created a new SDK folder and the problem was solved.